# What is a good alternative to Snowdon?

Tags: walking, wales

It is reported that Mount Snowdon, in Wales, [is becoming extremely congested with walkers](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-wales-58283816).

Snowdon has obvious advantages for the casual walker: it is a steady gradient up a selection of well trodden trails, there is a steam railway, a cafe at the top and a good view from the summit on a clear day.

Can anyone recommend other mountains in Snowdonia that are equivalently accessible to the casual walker (but without the cafe or railway perhaps)?

Comment: Snowdon *isn't* suitable for casual walkers. You see them set out at the bottom in flipflops and t shirts, but even the 'easy' walk becomes progressively harder. No mountain walk should be taken casually, but with informed preparation. The story quotes *"He warned large numbers of these visitors had not arrived properly prepared to walk up the 1,085m (3,560 ft) peak, with some dressed inappropriately and not having the fitness or hiking experience to get to the top."*

Comment: @weathervane Good point. By casual, I mean the sort of walk that doesn't need dedicated hiking skills or equipment beyond sensible clothing, footwear, water, a map, compass and the ability to assess a weather forecast.